# How to prevent the create/alter procedure/trigger if domain not correct? I tried something like below but does not seem to work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

--I do not want to create/alter the trigger if the domain=x

```
: ON ERROR EXIT 

USE [DB_Name]
GO


If default_domain()='x'
BEGIN
 RAISERROR (' Preventing deployment in this region. Please ignore the error message',11,1);
 RETURN
END
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'TR' AND name = 'tr_name_insert') 
        EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_name_insert]
ON  [dbo].[table_name]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 1
END')
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_name_insert]
ON  [dbo].table_name
FOR INSERT
.........SOME code
................
```

Comment: You'll need to expand on, "does not seem to work"

Comment: default_domain is a values send from the application or is the login?

Comment: So when I execute above code using sqlcmd, It does raises the error message but seems like it moves on to the next batch and tries to create a trigger. Another error message after the raiseerror I get is "table_name doesnot exists or invalid for this operation".  However, the table exists in the database. BUt I am not sure why is it even going to next batch where its trying to create the the trigger.

Comment: defualt_domain function is comparing one of the value in the metadata table in sql server which stores value for different domain types.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be as simple as a syntax error - a space between `:` and `ON ERROR EXIT`?

The file should start

```
:ON ERROR EXIT 

USE [DB_Name]
GO
```